# Is there way to rearange objects in array that the value becomes the key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I'm stuck on this type of situation where the values of the object is changed to a different value. Is there way to shift a value to a key or would simply deleting and adding be better? I tried to loop to see which of the keys overlap in value and using the if statement and conditions i tried adding or deleting using Array methods. However, since the inter data is an object i am sruggling to find the right methods or even the process. I also tried using a function to insert the data and pushing to a new empty array that is returned from the function.

If I have objects in an array like so:

```
const data = [
{
    "date": "12/22",
    "treatment": "nausea",
    "count": 2
},
{
    "date": "12/23",
    "treatment": "cold",
    "count": 3
},
{
    "date": "12/22",
    "treatment": "cold",
    "count": 2
}
];

and wanting to change the data like so:

const newData = [
{
    "date": "12/22",
    "cold": 2
    "nausea": 2,
},
{
    "date": "12/23",
    "cold": 3
}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code using  loop and reduce and every time add to new array

```js
const data = [
{
    "date": "12/22",
    "treatment": "nausea",
    "count": 2
},
{
    "date": "12/23",
    "treatment": "cold",
    "count": 3
},
{
    "date": "12/22",
    "treatment": "cold",
    "count": 2
}
];

const newData = [];
const dataByDate = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc[curr.date]) {
        acc[curr.date] = { date: curr.date };
    }
    acc[curr.date][curr.treatment] = curr.count;
    return acc;
}, {});

for (let date in dataByDate) {
    newData.push(dataByDate[date]);
}

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

We want to reduce the data by unique dates. This can be done with:

- An [object as a dictionary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps),
- [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), or
- Some other custom implementation.

Prefer to use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) when reducing an array. This is standardized and more expressive than a custom implementation.

Using a map-like structure as the accumulator allows reduction of the dates by uniqueness and the data itself, simultaneously.

**Note**: Properties of objects are converted to Strings (except for Symbols). So if you want to use different "keys" that are equal after conversion (e.g. `0` and `"0"`), you cannot use objects; use `Map` instead.
(All our dates are Strings already, so this warning does not apply here.)

When using an object we can use the [nullish coalescing assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment): This allows us to assign an initial "empty" entry (`{ date: dataEntry.date }`) when encountering a new unique date.

Further, that assignment evaluates to the dictionary's entry; the entry that was either already present or just assigned.

Then we only need to assign the treatment and its count as a key-value pair to the entry.

```js
const data = [
  { "date": "12/22", "treatment": "nausea", "count": 2 },
  { "date": "12/23", "treatment": "cold", "count": 3 },
  { "date": "12/22", "treatment": "cold", "count": 2 }
];

const newData = reduceByDate(data);
console.log(newData);

function reduceByDate(data) {
  const dataByDate = data.reduce((dict, dataEntry) => {
    const dictEntry = dict[dataEntry.date] // Get existing or ...
      ??= { date: dataEntry.date }; // ... just initialized entry.
    
    dictEntry[dataEntry.treatment] = dataEntry.count;
    return dict;
  }, {});
  
  // Transform dictionary to array of reduced entries
  return Object.values(dataByDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `reduce()` and `Object.assign()`.
First we use `reduce` to combine objects with the same date into one object and then use `assign` to merge the values:

```js
const data = [{
    "date": "12/22",
    "treatment": "nausea",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "date": "12/23",
    "treatment": "cold",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "date": "12/22",
    "treatment": "cold",
    "count": 2
  }
];

const newData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const dateIndex = acc.findIndex(item => item.date === curr.date);
  if (dateIndex === -1) {
    acc.push({
      date: curr.date,
      [curr.treatment]: curr.count
    });
  } else {
    acc[dateIndex] = Object.assign({}, acc[dateIndex], {
      [curr.treatment]: curr.count
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Why don't you _mutate_ the object instead of assigning a _new_ object?

Comment: You're right, mutating the object would be much smarter here